# Should we make a separate Rails App for our API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

We have a "big" site (50 scaffolds) running on Rails 2.3.9 with Heroku and we will want to add an API for 10% of our content.

Should we make a separate app on Rails 3.2 for our API? My guess is YES so it's more stable and faster to load. We will have a duplicate a bit of content but it's no big deal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your API is really simple and read-only than a separate app would not be unreasonable. However if you are going to write data then it's best if that is done through the same model API in both applications without duplicating code.

You may want to create a new set of controllers that are for the API only under an appropriate versioned namespace in your routes file.

Comment: I agree with Andrew. I recently had the same issue and I ended up adding JSON response to all my actions, keeping everything under one app, and generating a new set of controllers to handle api calls.

Answer (score 0):

I think `code replication` inside other app couldn't be a good choice instead you can implement API response inside you current app wherever required.

You can generate `authenticate_token` for external API access and authorize user based on token.